# how to get the latest and recent revision details of the code base in svn server?

Tags: svn

we are keeping the checked in code in our SVN server.

when I try "svn info" command ,it is giving the revision details of the working copy. Is there any command to get the  latest revision details of the code base in SVN server?

Comment: If you have not been provided with any training (or not enough), you should go read the [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need

```
svn log
```

or

```
svn diff [rev1]:[rev2]
```

Answer (score 0):

`svn help info` will tells you, that you can use URL as parameter for this command.

`svn info URL/OF/TRUNK` return information about state of node /trunk **on server**